# I have a problem in the unit test of spring + testng + mockito + powermock

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testng, powermock

I am unit testing the controller of the spring project, the controller code is as follows::

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ...

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/API/scanresultconfigure")

public class ScanResultConfigureController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ScanResultConfigureService scanResultConfigureService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public IBaseResult queryscanResultList(final HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final String taskId, @PathVariable final String externalname, @RequestBody Map map) throws Exception {
        return runController(new IControllRunner() {
            public void run(IOutResult or, CheckResult cr) throws Exception {
                Pageable p = getPageableFromRequest(map, "glt_msg", null);
                List list = scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(taskId, externalname, map);
                ......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used testng + mockito + powermock to unit test the controller.Because the controller extends BaseController (the code is as follows), when executing `Pageable p = getPageableFromRequest (map, "glt_msg", null);` NullPointerException will be reported.

BaseController::

```
package app.frame.vendor.spring.springmvc.common.usercontext;

import ...

public abstract class BaseController extends BaseController_Web {
    public BaseController() {
    }

    protected Pageable getPageableFromRequest(Map map, String gltName, Sort sort) {
        ...
        return pageable;
    }
}
```

The test class is as follows::

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ...

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
@ComponentScan(
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = {
                        ComponentScan.class, Configuration.class, ImportResource.class
                })
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        lazyInit = true
)
@EnableWebMvc
@PrepareForTest(BaseController.class)

public class ScanResultConfigureControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @MockBean(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private ScanResultConfigureService scanResultConfigureService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    }

     @Test
    public void testQueryscanResultList() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mock(BaseController.class);
        when(BaseController.getPageableFromRequest).thenReturn(Pageable);

        Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("key1", "value1");
        testMap.put("key2", "value2");
        String requestJson = JSONObject.toJSONString(testMap);
        List testList = new ArrayList();
        testList.add("test1");
        testList.add("test2");

        when(scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap())).thenReturn(testList);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                post("/API/scanresultconfigure/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", "123", "abc")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestJson)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

> The question I am confused about is :: how do I handle the `getPageableFromRequest` method of `BaseController` in that unit test.As we all know,the TestNG need to extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and the PowerMock need to extends `PowerMockTestCase`. How should I combine these two tools for unit testing in spring projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many experiments, it was found that the combination of SpringBootTest + TestNG + PowerMock does not work.The solution is: In the SpringBoot project tested by TestNG, use JMockit to simulate static methods, final methods, etc